# I want to sub in different arrays to a cell based upon the selection of a drop down menu

Tags: google-sheets

Assume I want a simple selection of “yes” or “no” in a drop down menu in google sheets. If yes, I want to take an array of 5 numbers from the c column. If no, I want to take an array of 5 numbers from the D column. My formula would look like this:
`=IFS(b1=“yes”, ARRAYFORMULA(c1:c5), b1=“no”, ARRAYFORMULA(d1:d5))`
When I try this with an =IF instead of =IFS, for example:

```
=IF(B1=“yes”, ARRAYFORMULA(C1:C5)
```

It works. Any advice on how I should do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrayformula should be outside:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1="yes", C1:C5, D1:D5))
```

If you want to use with `IFS`, all arguments should be of equal size:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(IF(SEQUENCE(5),B1)="yes",C1:C5,IF(SEQUENCE(5),B1)="no",D1:D5))
```

The condition `B1="yes"` is repeated as a array using `IF/SEQUENCE`